# Some claims on shortest path between two vertex in Diagraph?

Tags: data-structures, graph, tree, graph-theory, shortest-path

if we show the shortest path between two vertex with `delta(u,v)`, in a Weighted and Directed Graph ,G, (maybe we have negative edge) can I infer that:

> (1) -if we didnt have any negative cycle, then `delta(u,t) <= delta(u,v) + delta(v,t)`
>
> (2) -if we didnt have any negative cycle, then for each two vertex u,v, `delta(u,v)` is equal to    `-infinity`
>
> (3) -if we have negative edges, but didnt have any negative cycle, then `Sigma on delta(u,v)` (sum on all vertex pairs) cannot be negative.

there is not mentioned in (3), why is delta(u,v) where there's no path from u to v? maybe is 0, anyone can verify me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no and depends.

> -if we didnt have any negative cycle, then `delta(u,t) <= delta(u,v) + delta(v,t)`

From having `delta(u,v)` and `delta(v,t)`, we know that there's a path from `u` to `v` with length `delta(u,v)` and a path from `v` to `t` with length `delta(v,t)`. By concatenating them, we get a path from `u` to `t` with length `delta(u,v) + delta(v,t)`. Trivially, the length of shortest path from `u` to `t` is less or equal to the length of this path.

> -if we didnt have any negative cycle, then for each two vertex u,v, `delta(u,v)` is equal to `-infinity`

You probably wanted to write "*if we **did** have a negative cycle*"

That's not enough for making `delta(u,v)` equal to `-infinity` for any `u, v`; only for those where a path connecting them goes goes through any vertex of that cycle. In a strongly connected graph this would be true.

> -if we have negative edges, but didnt have any negative cycle, then `Sigma on delta(u,v)` (sum on all vertex pairs) cannot be negative.

For a digraph in general, this is not well defined - what is `delta(u,v)` where there's no path from `u` to `v`? If you say that `delta(u,v) = infinity` in that case, then your statement is true (same reason as below).

If you only consider strongly connected graphs, where every pair of vertices is connected and `delta(u,v)` defined, the sum of lengths must be non-negative. That's because for every distinct pair `u,v` the sum contains both `delta(u,v)` and `delta(v,u)`. Because there's no negative cycle, `delta(u,v) + delta(v,u) >= 0`. Except for these pairs of `delta(u,v)` and `delta(v,u)`, the sum only contains `delta(u,u) = 0` for all `u`. Summed up, we get a non-negative number.

Comment: is it possible to make example for each part? I confused :) , +1.

Comment: is it possible add an example to approve?

Comment: I Think you wrong, the OP in third sentences, means: sum of all delta (u, v) on each pair of vertexes is non-negative, and if there is no path the shortest path is 0. I think this is False.

Comment: we know just on of three sentence is True, maybe  user4249446 is right. please check it to approve.

Comment: pjtor, Hi, if we define delta(u,v) = 0, "then Sigma on delta(u,v) (sum on all vertex pairs) cannot be negative" is True? am I Right?